# Defining the behavior of a certain function composition

Tags: function-construction

I defined a function on objects of different types, `u[x_]` and `v[y_]`, as

```
u[x_] := x^2
v[y_] := y^3
f[u[x_]] := x + 1
f[v[y_]] := y/2
```

When I input `f[u[2]]`, I expect to get 5 as output. But I what I get is `f[4]` instead. Could someone tell me where it had gone wrong?

Comment: `u[2]` becomes 2^2 = 4 immediately, before `f` has a chance to see the structure. And `f` has no rules for input that don't have head `u`. Look up `HoldFirst`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the behavior you want giving `f` the attribute [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html), which prevents the premature evaluation of `u[x]` and `v[x]`.

```
Remove[f, u, v]
u[x_] := x^2
v[x_] := x^3
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[u[x_]] = 1 + u[x];
f[v[x_]] = v[x]/2;
```

then

```
{f[42], f[u[2]], f[v[3]]}
```

gives

> `{f[42], 5, 27/2}`

the behavior you expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do function composition, I think that's not the idea way to do it. If you intent to use f[u[x]], that's another story.

In:

```
Clear["Global`"]
u[x_] := x^2
v[y_] := y^3
f[x_] := x + 1

f@u[2]

h = f@*u;
h[2]
```

Out:

> 5
>
> 5